# Insert data into tables linked with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

First of all I tried this [Insert Data Into Tables Linked by Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997998/insert-data-into-tables-linked-by-foreign-key) and didn't get the answer.

I have 3 tables:

Table: **Customers**

```
ID -------LastName-------FirstName-------PhoneNumber
```

Table: **Order**

```
ID-------Status-------CustomerID
```

Table: **OrderLine**

```
ID-------OrderID-------Product-------Quantity-------PricePerUnit
```

I run the following query

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = 
   new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Order (Status, CustomerID) 
                    VALUES(13016, SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE FirstName = 'Garderp')", 
                  myConnection);`
```

and it throws exception

> Syntax error near Order

How can I add data into table with foreign key in SQL Server 2008 especially in this particular case?

Comment: FYI you can only accept one answer :)  I think Icarus has the most complete one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Order] (Status, CustomerID) " 
   + " SELECT 13016, ID 
       FROM Customers 
       WHERE FirstName = 'Garderp')"
, myConnection);
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is missing a (

Answer (score 5):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server (used in the `ORDER BY` operation).

You need to delimit that name with brackets:

`"INSERT INTO [Order] (Status, CustomerID) VALUES "`

That will cause SQL Server to treat it as an object name instead of reading it as a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Order is keyword in SQL, you have to bracket all keyword if you use it as table name or column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query

```
INSERT INTO [Order]
( Status, CustomerID )
SELECT 13016, ID
    FROM Customers
    WHERE FirstName = 'Garderp'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Order 
(Status, CustomerID)
VALUES " + "(13016, 
(SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE FirstName = 'Garderp'))", myConnection);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Order (Status, CustomerID) VALUES " + "(13016, SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE FirstName = \'Garderp\')", myConnection);
```

if there are more than one customer with name "Gardep", this query would fail. You  need to select only one record . Using TOP will be a better idea here

```
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Order (Status, CustomerID) VALUES " + "(13016, SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Customers WHERE FirstName = \'Garderp\')", myConnection);
```

Comment: -1 - you've provided 20 answers and should know how to mark code at this point.

Comment: Also it's a bad answer since you don't account for the reserved word use as a table name, and `TOP 1` will discard additional results he may want.

Comment: if u dont use top 1 and there are multiple rows, the query would fail.
You seem like a newbie. And NO, i dont know how to format the code. I believe if you have skills, you dont need spoon feeding

Comment: Actually it wouldn't fail if you made it `SELECT 13016, id from customers`, which is another reason this is a wrong answer - the approach is inappropriate for the issue.  Code tags are not about spoon feeding, they are to make the code more readable.