# Inverted commas in nested insert and select clause for sqlite in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am having an issue with placing the right qoutes in the following sqlite statement , which places the customer id(c_id) , a primary key of customers table , into the foreign key c_id of place table.

I could extract the c_id by un-nesting the code , and executing the portion 'select c_id from customers where fname =?" separately . However I want more conciseness in my code .

```
t = (fname,)
place = (postal_code , place_name)
cur.execute(""insert into place(postal_code ,place_name,c_id) values(?,?,("select c_id from customers where fname =?"),t)""",place)
```

The quotes are all out of place , help is appreciated for a fix .

Btw: This question is a similar duplicate of this question [Insert Data Into Tables Linked by Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997998/insert-data-into-tables-linked-by-foreign-key) , from which I copied the idea of nesting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem lies not in putting the right amount of quotation but in the form of the sqlite statement .

One solution is to design the variable place with three values, one of them with the foreign key of the customer id(c_id)

```
place = (postal_code , place , f_name) 

cur.execute("insert into place(postal_code ,place,f_name) values(?,?,(select c_id from customers where fname =?))",place)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely guessing here but have you tried.

```
cur.execute("insert into place(postal_code ,place_name,c_id) values(?,?,(select c_id from customers where fname = ?))", (postal_code , place_name, fname))
```

**Edit**
See this question [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

```
INSERT INTO TableA (colA, colB, colC) SELECT ?, ?, (SELECT c_id FROM customers WHERE fname = ?)
```

Comment: Its an issue with the inverted commas in python . I have to put them correctly so that the compiler understands that the select clause inside the values is a sql statement not something else .

Comment: Well it gives the error:                                 cur.execute("insert into place(postal_code ,place,c_id) values(?,?,(select c_id from customers where fname =?))",place,fname)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)