# INSERT to foreign table if it doesnt exist

Tags: database, postgresql, insert, foreign-key-relationship, common-table-expression

We've normalised our rather large table to separate store names and product details, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE store_products
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    storeid INTEGER REFERENCES store(id),
    productid BIGINT REFERENCES product_details(id)
    producturlid BIGINT REFERENCES product_url(id)
);
```

We get a dump of a stores products in JSON format and we iterate through each of the items and insert it into Postgres via a Delphi console app. It does this concurrently (so 4 threads insert and get through the JSON array of products).

It first checks if the store name exists in the `store` table, if not inserts it and caches the returning id, does the same for the `product` by name and `product_url` by url.

Is there a Postgres way of inserting data into this table (and foreign tables) in one go without having to do all these checks one by one? I had a look at CTE (WITH) but I'm unsure that's the solution to this problem.

The back and forth nature of the code and it being within a transaction becomes with heavy.

There are some [older SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997998/insert-data-into-tables-linked-by-foreign-key) that are similar, but the solutions don't seem to be viable. The one I'm looking at seems to be [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key) using USPERT and CTEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of playing around, I settled on the answer from this [stackoverflow post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key).

The answer is `Function with UPSERT in Postgres 9.5` by @Erwin Brandstetter, what a great way of doing it! so impressive.