# Normalize PostgreSQL staging table to existing Foreign Keys in lookup tables

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing Postgres database with a fact table and lookup tables.

We get the fact table transaction data from an API. This data is stored in a staging table in a second database, and is not normalized but it does have the same schema as the fact table.

1) How to I convert the staging table data to follow the form of the foreign keys in the lookup tables?

For example, the staging table might have the data "region B" in the region field, but before we insert the row into the fact table, I need to "convert" the "region B" value in the staging table to a "2" to match the lookup table below:

```
tbl_region
PK 
1  region A
2  region B
3  region C
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't looking at the correct terms so I didn't find these answers earlier. The core of the answer is going to be using a INSERT INTO with a select that looks up the FK.

Here are the references:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

and

[Insert Data Into Tables Linked by Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997998/insert-data-into-tables-linked-by-foreign-key)